# jQuery - remove video auto play on click

Tags: jquery, video, html5-video

I am using:

```
$("#vid1")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
```

to automatically start a video when a button is clicked and its sets the source as:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/LKFrlPDM6CE?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1
```

How can I remove the autoplay=1 and set it to autoplay=0 when I click a second button.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
var newSource = $("#vid1").attr('src').replace("&autoplay=1", "&autoplay=0");
$("#vid1").attr('src', newSource );
```

A few things to note:

> $("#vid1")[0]

The [0] isn't needed. You're selecting an ID and it should only appear once. If you were selecting a class that could appear more than once you'd use [`.eq(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

This will only work if you've already appended the `&autoplay=1` to the src. If this is a problem add a check to see if it's there or not.